# Merging Dictionaries that are <String, Any>

Tags: swift

I am trying to merge together two Dictionaries, both of this type:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>
```

I have been using code like this to merge them:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func extend(with:Dictionary){
        for (key,value) in with {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }
}

...

dict.extend(["num":123,"str":"abc","obj":UIColor.blueColor()])
```

This last line now produces an error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '(with: Dictionary<String, Any>)' to type 'Dictionary<String, NSObject>'
```

So Ive been trying to solve this by changing the declaration of `extend` to:

```
    mutating func extend(with:Dictionary<String, Any>
```

But this results in this line `self.updateValue` in producing this error:

```
'protocol<>' is not convertible to 'Value'
```

My best guess here is that `.updateValue` is an Objective C method, and Objective C struggles with the `Any` data type.

So my next move was to try and convert my `<String, Any>` object into a `<String, NSObject>` object in the hope that `.updateValue` will accept it. However when I try this:

```
var dict2 = Dictionary<String, NSObject>
```

Xcode wants to put a semi colon after the NSObject. If I do that it complains about something else. Ive seen this before, it seems like Xcode can tell something is not right, but it cant put its finger on it.

---

So my issue is this:

- I have two dictionaries.
- They both have to be `<String, Any>`.
- I have to merge them together into one.

Anyone have any idea's on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
dict.extend(with:["num":123,"str":"abc","obj":UIColor.blueColor()])
            ^^^^^
```

the first parameter of class/struct methods has no automatic external name, so you have to call as:

```
dict.extend(["num":123,"str":"abc","obj":UIColor.blueColor()])
```

If you want to use the external name, you have to explicitly declare it:

```
mutating func extend(withDict with:Dictionary) {
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

or if you want to use the same as the local name:

```
mutating func extend(# with:Dictionary){
                     ^
```

Suggested reading: [External Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254)

This is the code I used for testing:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()

extension Dictionary {
    mutating func extend(with:Dictionary){
        for (key,value) in with {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }
}

dict.extend(["num":123,"str":"abc","obj":UIColor.blueColor()])
```

Comment: Xcode has no problem with the way I am calling Parameter Names. Also the Parameter Names is not the problem I am having, neither is it what I have asked for help with. Seriously, if I comment out the contents of these functions, the program compiles fine with these Parameter Names. The problem is not the Parameter Names. The problem is merging two Dictionaries that are <String, Any>. Can you offer any help with this?

Comment: The code you posted, after applying any of the change I suggested, works and I see the dictionary, initially empty, updated with the new values.

Comment: Could I see the complete code please? As the Parameter Names aren't causing any issues at this end, and I have tried your suggestions and they aren't solving the problems I am having.

Comment: Code added to my answer

Comment: I apologize, I have had some bad experience on this site with people leaving answers that clearly indicate that they havent read or understood my question. I assumed that your answer was another like this and I was wrong. Totally my bad. Your code helped me find a solution to my problem, so many thanks for your time and your patience with me. I will endeavour to be more patient myself in the future.

Comment: Glad it worked. It can happen I give wrong answers, or misunderstand the problem, but on this I was pretty sure it was what I said in my answer ;-)